# SciPy ODE solver has problems with discrete events

Tags: python, events, scipy, simulation, solver

I am using the [SciPy ODE Integrator Class](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html) in order to solve an ordinary differential equation system. The complete program is supposed to simulate a mechanical system and visualize it with a 3D-Animation. This works fine as long as I really just want to solve a normal differential equation. However, some of the system state variables of the mechanical system are limited in their value range. These variables are not allowed to shoot over/go below a certain limit. 
My current approach to keep x_n < limit_{x_n}  is to detect it and return dx_n/dt = 0. The solver doesn't seem to like it. Minimal code of the problem:

```
solver = scipy.integrate.ode(rhs)
solver.set_initial_value(...) #not important
solver.set_integrator("vode", method="adams", rtol=1e-6, atol=1e-9)
...
while(True):
    state = solver.integrate(solver.t + timeStep)
    visualizeModel(state)
    ...

def rhs(t, x):
    x1, x2, x3 = x
    dx1dt = x1_dot(x1, x2, x3)
    dx2dt = x2_dot(x1, x2, x3)
    dx3dt = x3_dot(x1, x2, x3)
    if numpy.abs(x1) > my_limit:
        dx1dt = 0 #the solver seems to absolutely hate this line
    return [dx1dt, dx2dt, dx3dt]
```

```

How can I prevent the solver from stalling at this point? How can I implement a limited value range for variables of the differential equation?

Comment: Since not all ODEs can be solved the same way, it might help if you show us runnable code (or at least `x1_dot`, ..., `x3_dot`). It may help us find a solution which we can test that works for your situation.